# whats the best architecture for magento in AWS ec2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, pagespeed, speedoptimization

I am using magento 2.3 on AWS ec2 but the performance is quite not good full website load is about 5 sec.

I am using following structure :

- Application instance : EC2 t2.xlarge
- Mysql RDS : db.t3.large
- AWS CloudFront for media images

I am ready to change the instance types or adding any additional services. but need the website to load within 2-3 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow these steps and instance updates

1. UpGrade Magento to latest stable 2.4.1 & also check if any updates are there for 3rd party modules.
2. Install and configure Elastic Search
3. Update your application instance to c5d.xlarge or c5d.2xlarge
4. Initially create a backup and remove RDS then install Mysql Server on the same instance.
5. Install and configure Redis-cache
6. Configure fastly for better results of caching.
7. Check if any cacheable false blocks are there in layout XML files.

let me know if you need any more help.
kindly accept as a solution if this works for you.

Comment: elastic search required for 2.4.1 ? can I use mysql only

Comment: It's better to use Elastic search as it also give you improvement in search and categories listing page. and you are also planning to re-structure so plan for that.

Comment: i'll try this with my system admin and update you

Comment: I am having issues with point no 7 : i had a price block with cacheable="false" when i removed i got error for getFinalPrice() on null

Comment: check the block of that phtml & update the code to get the product from the registry, your problem should be solved.

Comment: thanks @amitsamsukha